# IDE for Google Earth app using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, development-environment, google-earth-plugin

Is there a recommended IDE for developing Browser based Google Earth app using JavaScript ?

Comment: vim is the answer for every coding need!

Comment: are there any tutorials for this ? Yes, if you are good with linux and ready to spent time learning vi shortcuts etc then this might work.  I just want to throw something together for a client in 3 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have quite a good set up using visual web developer for my IDE. The thing you are looking for is JavaScript debugging tools as these can really help to troubleshoot issues. Check the development pages on the earth api documentation for a great list of available tools. However it is worth noting that none are "recommended" as such...

http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/debugging.html

Comment: Thanks.  Can you please elaborate on the "good set up using visual web developer" part.

Comment: Sure, I use a set up pretty much like the one outlined here - http://berniesumption.com/software/how-to-debug-javascript-in-internet-explorer/ the only difference is that I work from a local page rather than navigating in step 4. I also sometimes use VS Express 2010 as a javascript editor to build complex functions using the API. Here I simply reference the "Google Earth Plugin Type Library" and set up a dummy ge object (IGEPlugin ge = null) then as I code I have full intellisense support and type checking on the api. Obviously, I can then transfer this clean code to a html file.

Answer (score 1):

Use whatever you're used to.  There is no canonical IDE for using Google's APIs with JavaScript.

Comment: Sure.  Just wanted to know if there is a 'recommended' or popular IDE people use.